# What types of input should I use in this neural network?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, nlp, accord.net

I have a system in which users can send many chat messages, and many of them tend to be questions, like `How do I register an account?`
`How do I do this?` `Where is X?`

To help with this, I'm interested in creating a `FAQbot` that takes a chat message then decides whether to send a helpful message explaining how to do things. So a user types in `How do I register an account?` and the bot should reply something along the lines of `You can register by ...` The bot should reply like that if the user types `How do I register?`, `I can't register an account!`, `Can somebody please tell me how to register?`, or anything else like that. There would be a fixed set of answers this bot would give to various questions we'd expect users to have, so I plan on training the neural network to `output 0` for a message that doesn't need a reply, or some other `ID number` that corresponds to a given reply message.

I was thinking that I would log all chat messages, go through and classify them all with which message or no message would be an appropriate reply, and then feed that into a neural network. I would also create tools to correct inappropriate replies or lack thereof.

I'm using `C#` and will probably use a library such as `Accord.NET`, although I'm not asking for the specific implementation. My one question is how I would take the chat message string and turn it into valid input for the neural network. I imagine it would tell the network which words and punctuation were used, which order the words were in, and which words follow which other words. However, the specific implementation of that eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - seems like your task is some kind of `natural text classification`(each FAQ question presents one class).

Also - maybe `TF-IDF`vector?
Another way that I see - present input as matrix of word vector (from word2vec or something like it), but seems like in this case ANN will have many params - so it not seems like you'll can train it properly.

p.s. also - maybe you'll prefer [api.ai](https://api.ai/), or, maybe - Watson nlc-based bot?